# Invertir orden de elementos de una lista en Python

Tags: python

Esta es mi primera pregunta y si no está fuera de las reglas, quisiera que me ayudaran a comprender este código, específicamente una linea. Estoy haciendo un curso de Python en Cisco. En el ejemplo que dejo abajo  se invierte el orden de los elementos de la lista. Entiendo que:" **my_list[length - i - 1]** " en cada iteración se refiere al último elemento, pero no entiendo por qué. ¿Sería 5 -i -1? ¿Como llega al ulitmo elemento con esto?

```
my_list = [10, 1, 8, 3, 5]
length = len(my_list)

for i in range(length // 2):
    my_list[i], my_list[length - i - 1] = my_list[length - i - 1], my_list[i]

print(my_list)
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: La forma pythonica de invertir una lista es `lista[::-1]`. El método que expones se usa en lenguajes primitivos.

Comment: Entiendo. Me gustaría comprenderlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Como usar listas en Python

En este ciclo

```
for i in range(length // 2):
    my_list[i], my_list[length - i - 1] = my_list[length - i - 1], my_list[i]
```

estas haciendo un intercambio de variables. Esta expresión es del tipo

```
a, b = b, a
```

donde Python primero evuala el lado derecho, obteniendo los valores `a` y `b`. Luego de obtener los valores y guardarlos en variables temporales, procede al reemplazo de las variables en el lado izquierdo. No hay confusión, pues los valores ya están calculados.

`my_list[i]` obviamente es el elemento i-esimo desde el principio de la lista.
`my_list[length - i - 1]` es el elmento i-esimo desde el final. `lenght - 1` es el índice del último elemento. Si le restamos `i`, que va de cero en adelante, iremos recorriendo del último hacia el primero.

Entonces, si ejecutamos manualmente la iteración, tenemos las siguientes asignaciones:

```
my_list[0], my_list[4] = my_list[4], my_list[0]
my_list[1], my_list[3] = my_list[3], my_list[1]
```

que intercambian los elementos de la lista.

Para aclarar el tema de los indices en Python,

**Elemento por elemento**

Puedes acceder a cualquier elemento usando la notación `lista[x]`, donde 'x' es un valor entre 0 y `n-1`, siendo `n` el número de elementos en la lista.

También puedes usar indices negativos, que se cuentan desde el último elemento. Así, `lista[-1]` es el último elemento (`n - 1`), `lista[-2]` es el penúltimo (`n - 2`), etc.

**Rebanada de listas**

Puedes acceder a un rango de elementos (*tajada*, *rebanada* o *slice*) poniendo el indice de inicio y final separados por `:`. El rango **no** incluye el elemento señalado por el índice final.

En una rebanada de listas se pueden omitir los indices inicial y final. Si no se colocan, se usa cero y -1 respectivamente.

La expresión `lista[1:3]` produce una lista de 2 elementos:

```
my_list = [10, 1, 8, 3, 5]
print(my_list[1:3])
```

produce `[1, 8]`.

Esto admite combinaciones. Por ejemplo, puedes usar indices negativos:

```
my_list = [10, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11]
print(my_list[1:-2])
```

produce `[1, 8, 3, 5, 7]`.

**Cambiando el orden**

También puedes indicar un tercer parámetro en la rebanada que indica de cuanto en cuanto avanzar el indice que recorre la lista. Este parámetro también se separa con ":"

Si quieres recorrer los elementos de dos en dos, puedes usar

```
lista[::2]
```

Si el valor es negativo, entonces la lista se recorre en orden inverso

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(my_list[::-1])
```

produce `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Si quieres procesar sólo una rebanada de la lista, debes invertir los indices de principio y final:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(my_list[3::-1])
```

produce `[4, 3, 2, 1]`

Ojo: No pusimos el indice inicial y tomó por default el primer elemento de la lista, pero si pones explicitamente cero, no da igual:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(my_list[3:0:-1])
```

produce `[4, 3, 2]` porque el proceso termina al llegar al indice final (cero en este caso), el que no se procesa.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta y por haberte tomado el tiempo para explicarme en detalle.